# WordNet, Query Expansion, Step by Step

Tags: wordnet, expansion

I want to make a project about query expansion using WordNet,but it's hard to find step by step method to do it.

Based on [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11835/WordNet-based-semantic-similarity-measurement), I should take the following steps (assuming a sentence as input to the program):

1. Tokenization
2. Tagging part of speech
3. Stemming word
4. Word sense disambiguation
5. Semantic similarity between the two synsets (it still confusing)

...and then we can conclude that the word with larger score is the query expansion from the input. However, I'm still confused about how to perform each of these steps. Is there any source which covers these in more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query Expansion is a huge field in itself under IR (Information Retrieval).

Also, WordNet is by itself huge, and so it is difficult to find single step-by-step directions.
However, there are tons of very good resources. I got started with it by taking several web examples and trying them out myself.

Resources you will find useful in getting started.

1. The [wordnet site](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) itself (with examples)
2. The [WordNet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordnet) Wikipedia page
3. Python Programming.net has a [WordNet tutorial page](https://pythonprogramming.net/wordnet-nltk-tutorial/)
4. Even if you don't know Python, I would highly recommend the O'Reilly book "**Natural Language Processing with Python**". It's [website](http://nltk.org/book/) has TONS of examples to get you started.

Hope that helps you get going.

Comment: Oke, but i want to make it in java, using JAWS and semantic similarity library for java. thank you, maybe i can contact you Ram Narasimhan?